# I need to call two functionality on clicking of save button

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Whenever i click a save button it need to insert and send email ,for that i used addRecord method for inserting record and in the same function  i called send mail functionality by calling the object .
send mail code:

```
RacMail obj=new RackMail();
return  obj.getSendMail(r.id);
```

How to call in vf one after other ?

Comment: why don't you call second method from first method inside apex?

Comment: You mean i need to create two methods in current controller  for inserting and sending mail?   i created send mail functionality in other class

Comment: Just create a single method and write all logic and call that method.

Answer (score 1):

In order to write reusable code, separation of concerns, or whatever you want to call it:

1. One method for the save
2. One method for the sending of the email
3. Could also have a third method saveaandemail that calls both

Now you can do one of the following to execute them in once click:

1. Execute the saveaandemail method **OR** save method from page action, then call email method in save method
2. Execute the save method from page action, oncomplete of that action call another page action to execute method that sends the email.

The latter being more complex than needed here but can be useful if you need to do DML and them make a callout from the VF page after the DML

Comment: Or you could write a separate method for each (`save` and `email`), and then have a method that calls both (`saveAndEmail`). It might be easier to test that way.